# Recursion - Cracking random generated password

Tags: java, recursion, passwords, brute-force

So I have gotten it to find the number of attempts it takes to crack the generated 5 digit password however it's using a while loop to do it instead of Recursion. I have reduced the number of letters just to make it run faster and to test out the code. What changes would I need to make so it cracks the password using recursion instead of a for/while loop? This is my entire code so far:

```
//imports
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

class Main {
public static Random rr = new Random();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Letters for the random generated password
    // Variables
    String letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
    int PASSWORD = letters.length();
    // While statement to allow user to keep generating passwords
    while (true) {
        String password = "";
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Print menu and uses 1 to generate password
        System.out.println("Press 1 to generate a random password");
        // Takes user input
        int UserOption = input.nextInt();
        // If user input equals 1
        if (UserOption == 1) {
            // Generate a 5-character passwords from the letters in the String
            //Print text is outside the loop to prevent it from printing it more than once in one try
            System.out.println("Your password is: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                password = password + letters.charAt(rr.nextInt(PASSWORD));
            }
            //To print the password and the number of attempts it took
            System.out.println(password);
            passCracking(password, letters, 0, "");
        }
        // If user input is anything except 1
        else if (UserOption != 1) {
            // Print error
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}
// Method that creates random 5 digit strings and checks if it matches with the password
//Password Generator
private static String comparePass(String characters) {
    String comparePass = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        comparePass = comparePass + characters.charAt(rr.nextInt(characters.length()));
    }
    return comparePass;
}
//Recursive Method 
private static int passCracking(String password, String characters, int tries, String check) {
    //Base Case
    //If the password matches then return 0 to let the loop know we found the match and ends cracking the password
    if (check.equals(password)) {
        return 0;
    }
    //After checking it once, it checks again but if it doesn't match return -1 and does backtrack and calls upon the method again with different password combination
    else if (!check.equals("")) {
        if (!check.equals(password)) {
            return-1;
        }
    }
    //While loop where it keeps looping when its not the correct password
    while (true) {
        check = comparePass(characters);
        if (passCracking(password, characters, tries++, check) == 0) {
            //Print statement for number of attempts
            System.out.println("It took " + tries + " tries to crack the password");
            //Returns zero
            return 0;
        }
        //Add one to the attempt counter for every attempt in cracking the password
        tries++;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Recursion would make sense if you could check each individual byte for success/failure then continue/fallback depending on the result. It wouldn't really make sense IMO if you have to compare an entire 5 byte string..

Comment: I agree with you and that's what I've done before however, I wanted to know if it's possible to compare the entire 5-byte string with other temp strings as attempts. Do you have any ideas on how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (mostly) recursive solution that checks each permutation of characters in the given `charset` up to some max length for the password `maxPwdLength`. You could still replace the `for` loop with an additional layer of recursion.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        String charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
        String pwd = crackPassword("", 5, charset);
        System.out.println(pwd);
    }

    public static boolean checkPassword(String guess) {
        String ACTUAL_PASSWORD = "pwd01";  // Whatever the actual password is
        return guess.equals(ACTUAL_PASSWORD);
    }

    public static String crackPassword(String currentGuess, int maxPwdLength, String charset) {
        if (checkPassword(currentGuess)) {
            return currentGuess;  // This means we cracked the password
        }
        if (currentGuess.length() == maxPwdLength) {
            return null;
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < charset.length(); i++) {
            String nextGuess = currentGuess + charset.charAt(i);
            String result = crackPassword(nextGuess, maxPwdLength, charset);
            if (result != null) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return null; 
    }
}
```

---

The bigger question at play here is do you really want to use recursion for this problem? Recursion can lead to some elegant solutions, but function calls aren't free, so making a lot of them with recursion can hurt performance. In this case, an iterative solution would probably be more performant.

Comment: I totally agree with you however, for this assignment it's required to use recursion to crack the password.

Comment: @UO23 Fair enough. This answer should get you pretty far along the way. It wouldn't be prudent for me to do the assignment for you since that would rob you of the learning experience. That said, If you need to do it without any loops at all, converting a for loop into a recursive function isn't hard. Instead of counting up, pass ever decreasing values into a recursive function then start returning up the call stack once you reach 0 or crack the password.